# Self-made attribute mask in QGIS and current_value() function

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer, multi-values

I'm working on a QGIS-Project and I tried to design my own formmask/attributemask with QT Designer. I use QGIS 3.28.12

Most of the Mask works perfectly fine, except for two things.

The second of which I'm asking here.

**Problem:**
I've a field, where I use a Value Relation and then a "current_value()" function to automatically have values depending on what was chosen in the field beforehand.

In my old mask it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

But when I want to implement the mask I created with qt designer, it doesn't work anymore. This happens:

[image]

The second field doesn't update according to the first chosen field anymore, but just shows the whole list. The current_value function is still there, same as before.

[image]

Is it possible, that I can't use the current_value() function when designing my own mask or do I need to add the function somewhere else?

It's my first time working with self-designed masks.

Answer (score 1):

After all this time and with help from a QGIS Developer we found out, that there's actually nothing wrong with the funktion and ui-form...
it seems the problem is a bug in newer QGIS-Versions, so not much I can do about it.

If a solution is found to fix the bug or some workaround, I'll post here as an answer.